# Data-Tables desalinhando o título e corpo da tabela quando é aplicado scroll

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-datatables

Estou tentando aplicar o plugin `DataTables` às tabelas de meu template, o problema é que quando aplico o *scroll*, a tabela acaba desalinhando o título da tabela do seu respectivo corpo de dados.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayconfsbrito/faJkw/27/)

Comment: Eu fiz aqui e não vi tal diferença? como assim ... !!! ???

Comment: @Fúlvio Tens de fazer scroll para a direita.

Comment: Então o meu ta normal !!! kkkk

Comment: Sim. No caso da tabela de exemplo deste Fiddle o problema está acontecendo nas colunas finais da tabela. Porém, em outras tabelas do sistema que tenho aqui, o problema ocorre nas primeiras colunas também.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu abri um tópico relacionado a este problema no Stack Overflow internacional onde minha pergunta foi parcialmente solucionada. Apesar do novo problema encontrado a partir da resposta, acredito que o mesmo seja relacionado ao meu template, e não somente a tabela em si. Então, para não emendar a dúvida deste tópico com outra, e também conceder os devidos créditos ao autor da solução, posto no link abaixo o link para o fiddle e o tópico com a solução. Obrigado!

[Tópico com a solução](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937990/data-table-misaligning-the-title-and-body-of-the-table-when-scroll-is-apply/22939001?noredirect=1#comment35032843_22939001)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YL7hZ/)

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu percebi o comportamento é normal, uma vez que estás a fazer o *scroll* do body da tabela e não a tabela em si. Se reparares o *scroll* vertical não inclui o *header* da tabela.

Ou seja, depois ao fazer o *scroll* horizontal quando a tabela acaba, o *header* fica justo a direita, e para conseguires ver o *body* da tabela tens de continuar a fazer *scroll*, dai o "desalinhar", que na verdade não acontece. Entendeste?

Vê a imagem:
[image: imagem]

Comment: Realmente faz sentido, porém não sei qual seria a solução para este caso. O que você me sugere?

Comment: Pelo que vejo [aqui](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html) acho que é assim mesmo que funciona. Talvez tenhas de mexer no javascript do datatable mesmo.

Comment: O teu problema ai é provavelmente estares a usar o `script` do `Bootstrap` com esse. [Aqui](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_xy.html) está um exemplo a funcionar direito. Tenta por isso a funcionar sem o js `Bootstrap`, se funcionar já vais saber o porque disso.

Comment: Dá uma vista de olhos [nisto](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/7637)

Comment: Sim, pode ser que seja o script bootstrap. Mas o meu template não pode ficar sem ele, pois faz parte da aplicação.